# ECW on Mac Osx 10.8 Mountain Lion

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, ecw

I'm having some problems with GdalTools on QGIS 1.8, with MacOsx 10.8: I've the GDAL complete library 1.9 but ECW is still a not supported format.

What should I do?